# forecasting in arima using python

Tags: python, prediction, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I have created an ARIMA model like this

```
for i in range(len(testy)):
    model = ARIMA(endog=trainy,exog=trainx,order=(1,0,1))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    ll=testx[i]
    yhat = model_fit.forecast(exog=ll)
    pred.append(yhat[0])
    actual = testy[i]
    all_values.append(actual)
    #print('=%f\t=%f' % (yhat[0], actual))
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat[0], actual))
```

Now I am looking to forecast the future values for next 12 weeks. is it possible?

```
# Forecast
start_index = len(df.values)
end_index = start_index + 6
forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
print(forecast)
```

when I use the above code snippet I am getting the error as shown below.

```
 ValueError: You must provide exog for ARMAX
```

Edit: Libraries used are:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import log
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from scipy.stats import boxcox
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
#from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf
```

Comment: how are we supposed to know what library you are using?

Comment: Hello Chris, I have added the libraries. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a valid parameter https://www.statsmodels.org/0.8.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict

Comment: yes, I got that snippet from autoarima. could you please suggest to me any alternate way? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the method predict does not have a keyword argument `n_periods` use `start`and `end` from the help of `ARIMA.predict` you can find the description of the arguments:

```
start : int, str, or datetime
    Zero-indexed observation number at which to start forecasting, ie.,
    the first forecast is start. Can also be a date string to
    parse or a datetime type.
end : int, str, or datetime
    Zero-indexed observation number at which to end forecasting, ie.,
    the first forecast is start. Can also be a date string to
    parse or a datetime type. However, if the dates index does not
    have a fixed frequency, end must be an integer index if you
    want out of sample prediction
```

[Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/) is a good example of how to make a multi-step forecast.

Comment: as suggested I went across the example and added  ```
start_index = len(df.values)
end_index = start_index + 6
forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
print(forecast)```

in the model, I get the error ```ValueError: You must provide exog for ARMAX
```

Comment: what should be the start index?  len(testx)?